# OpenGL - get mouse position co-ordinates

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, mouse, point

I am making a 2D board game. the game board grid is 8x8 and each cell of the grid is an object. So a board consists of 64 cell objects. My aim is to work out which cell the mouse is in. I am attempting this by tracking the mouse coordinates and comparing it to the grid coordinates.

my coordinate system is as follows:

```
gluOrtho2D(-4,4,-4,4);
```

I am trying to get the current mouse position by using the following in my update function:

```
POINT p

if (GetCursorPos(&p)){

}

if (ScreenToClient(hWnd, &p))
{

}
```

However although this is tracking the coordinates of the mouse it is not correctly tracking the world coordinates that I set with gluOrtho2D. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your glViewPort

Let's say you have:
glViewport(0,0, 640, 640);

The mouse position is (mousePos.x,mousePos.y) and the world position you want to know is (world.x, world.y)

And, give that the top/left corner of your screen is the (0, 0) coordinate

Then we can make the following:

world.x = -4.0 + (mousePos.x / 640.0) * (4*2)

world.y =  4.0 - (mousePos.y / 640.0) * (4*2)

What we are doing here is a linear interpolation using the normalize position of the mouse within the screen (mousePos.x / 640) and then multiplying this value to the width of the word (4*2). 
Given that the top/left corner of the grid start at (-4, 4), we add the offset of the world position.